# How to protect a worksheet and unprotect a list object in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running excel 2010 and have developed a xlsm to roll out to a few users

I have protected the workbook with the following routine which works well

My problem is I have used listobjects in the workbook as mapping tables which require intervention by the users. The existing listobject rows can be manipulated but no new rows can be added - Any ideas on how I can get around this ?

thanks

```
Public Sub ProtectAll(ByVal wbWorkbook As Workbook)

  Dim wks As Worksheet

  For Each wks In wbWorkbook.Worksheets
                wks.Protect sPasswordToLock, True, True, False, True,     True,True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True
                wks.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions

  Next wks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this though the answer is more complicated than you maybe expect. Jon van der Heyden used to have a good article about this on his site (exceldesignsolutions.com) but I think he has removed it. I adopted some of his code that will allow you to add rows to a listobject on a protected sheet. The nice thing about this is that it forces the user to only enter data in the row immediately below the listobject, which ensure that the listobject "grows" to include the new data.

In a nutshell, the method used is to create a custom class that will contain a listobject and an event handler that listens for a change to the sheet containing it. If the change is in the row immediately below the listobject then undo the change, unprotect the sheet, redo the change and reprotect the sheet. In addition unlock the row immediately below the listobject.

Here is what to do:

In your workbook containing the listobjects, create a custom class module and name it cProtectedLO. Paste the following code into it:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_loTable As ListObject
Private m_strPassWord As String
Private WithEvents m_appExcel As Excel.Application

Public Property Set Table(ByVal loTable As ListObject)
    Set m_loTable = loTable
End Property

Public Property Let Password(ByVal strPassword As String)
    m_strPassWord = strPassword
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_appExcel = Excel.Application
End Sub

Private Sub m_appExcel_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngTable As Excel.Range
    Dim varValue As Variant

    Set rngTable = m_loTable.Range

    If Sh Is rngTable.Parent Then
        If Not Intersect(Target.Offset(-1), rngTable) Is Nothing Then
            If Intersect(Target, rngTable) Is Nothing Then
                varValue = Target.Value
                Sh.Unprotect Password:=IIf(Len(m_strPassWord), m_strPassWord, Null)
                With Application
                    .EnableEvents = False
                    .Undo
                    Target.Value = varValue
                    Sh.Cells.Locked = True
                    m_loTable.DataBodyRange.Locked = False
                    m_loTable.Range(m_loTable.Range.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, m_loTable.ListColumns.Count).Locked = False
                    .EnableEvents = True
                End With
                Sh.Protect Password:=IIf(Len(m_strPassWord), m_strPassWord, Null)
                Target.Offset(1).Select
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_loTable = Nothing
    Set m_appExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Add a normal code module and paste this code in it:

```
Option Explicit

Public m_colProtectedLO As Collection

Public Sub EnableProtectedTables(Optional ByVal pw As Variant)

    Dim clsProtectedLO As cProtectedLO
    Dim wks As Worksheet, lo As ListObject

    Set m_colProtectedLO = New Collection

    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        For Each lo In wks.ListObjects
            Set clsProtectedLO = New cProtectedLO

            With clsProtectedLO
                Set .Table = lo

                If Not IsMissing(pw) Then
                    .Password = pw
                End If

            End With

            wks.Unprotect Password:=pw
            lo.DataBodyRange.Locked = False
            lo.Range(lo.Range.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, lo.ListColumns.Count).Locked = False
            wks.Protect Password:=pw
            m_colProtectedLO.Add Item:=clsProtectedLO
        Next lo

    Next wks

 End Sub
```

In the ThisWorkbook module, paste the following:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    EnableProtectedTables
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Set m_colProtectedLO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note that is the sheets are password protected you would have to include it as a value for the "pw" argument in the call to EnableProtectedTables, like this:

```
EnableProtectedTables pw:="YourPasswordHere"
```

Save the workbook, close it and open it again and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks the solution works , I didn't anticipate so much code. 2 questions :- any reason why the protect method in vba doesn't have a parameter for the list object. Also is there a reason why the worksheet Change event in the above code is in the class rather than utilising the worksheet_change within excel? Thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer to your first question. As for the second, if you used the worksheet_change event you would have to add the code to each sheet in the workbook that contains list objects. By placing it in the class event and storing an instance of the class for each list object in a global collection you require much less coding, and it works even if you don't know how many (and where) list objects there are.

Comment: You can also add new listobjects (in new sheets if desired) and it will still work, though you would have to close and open the workbook again.

Comment: Just for the sake of handling the cases where tables are empty, you could add `If Not lo.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then` `lo.DataBodyRange.Locked = False` `End If` in the EnableProtectedTables procedure